# Use cases for function type typedefs with qualifiers

Tags: c++

One can `typedef` function types, even with class cv- and ref-qualifiers:

```
typedef void F() const volatile &&;
```

This can be used to declare (but not define) non-static member functions:

```
struct A {
    F f;    // void f() const volatile &&
};
```

This use for `F` is explicitly forbidden in dependent contexts in templates.

It can also be used as template argument. As far as I can tell, there is however no way of extracting or manipulating the cv- and ref-qualifiers of the type.

Is there any other use case for such a `typedef` (with any qualifier, not necessarily all of them at once)?

Comment: This may be worthwhile reading for you http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html

Comment: @StoryTeller that's an excellent read! Thank you.

Comment: @StoryTeller So the qualifiers are accessible via template specialization. I don't know why I overlooked that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard specifies the only allowed use cases of such function types (function types with a *cv-qualifier-seq* or a *ref-qualifier*) in [[dcl.fct]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct#6):

> A function type with a *cv-qualifier-seq* or a *ref-qualifier*
>   (including a type named by *typedef-name* ([dcl.typedef],
>   [temp.param])) shall appear only as:
>
> - (6.1) the function type for a non-static member function,
> - (6.2) the function type to which a pointer to member refers,
> - (6.3) the top-level function type of a function typedef declaration or *alias-declaration*,
> - (6.4) the *type-id* in the default argument of a *type-parameter*, or
> - (6.5) the *type-id* of a template-argument for a *type-parameter* ([temp.arg.type]).

Minimal <s>reproducible</s> representative example (mre):

```
using Func = void() const;
using Func2 = Func;       // (6.3)

struct C {
    Func f;               // (6.1)
};

Func C::* ptr;            // (6.2)

template <class T = Func> // (6.4)
struct S { };

S<Func> x;                // (6.5)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the (relatively more) important case I missed is (6.2) when used in a generic code, as the document linked by StoryTeller in the comments demonstrates as well.